# Show the identity map and the map $g(x,y)=(-x,-y)$ are homotopic maps from $S^1$ to itself

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, homotopy-theory

This is a homework problem for a point-set topology course.
$\DeclareMathOperator{\img}{im}$

View $S^1$ as the unit circle $S^1 := \{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2 \mid x^2 +y^2 = 1\}$. Let $f,g:S^1 \to S^1$ be the maps $f(x,y)=(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)=(-x,-y)$. Prove that $f$ and $g$ are homotopic.

**Question.** Is the below proof of this statement correct? (Edit: In particular, I am unsure about proving continuity rigorously.)

*Proof.* We proceed to show $f$ and $g$ are homotopic by construction of a homotopy ${F:S^1 \times I\to S^1}$ from $f$ to $g$.
For each $(x,y)\in S^1$, define the map $\underset{x,y}{\Psi}:I\to S^1$ to be the clockwise path in $S^1$ from $(x,y)$ to $(-x,-y)$. Now let $F$ be given by $F\left( (x,y),t \right) = \underset{x,y}{\Psi}(t)$, and we claim $F$ is a homotopy from $f$ to $g$.

When $t=0,1$ it is easy to see that $F$ is equivalent to $f$ and $g$, respectively. It remains to show that $F$ is continuous, or equivalently that the preimage of a basic open set is open.

[Side note: I guess it should be obvious that $F$ is continuous? But for sake of completeness here is my attempt at proving it.]

Let $U\subseteq S^1$ be a basic open set with respect to the basis of $\mathbb R^2$ comprised of open balls. Then $U=S^1\cap B$ for some open ball $B\subseteq \mathbb R^2$. If $U=S^1$, then $F^{-1}(U)=S^1 \times I$ and we are done. Assuming $U\neq S^1$, then $U$ is homeomorphic to an open interval, and $S^1 \setminus U$ to a closed interval. Let $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ be the endpoints of the arc $S^1\setminus U$, and then its preimage is given by
\begin{equation}
F^{-1}(S^1 \setminus U) = \left( \img \underset{-a,-b}{\Psi} \cup \img \underset{-c,-d}{\Psi} \right) \times I.
\end{equation}
Since $\img \underset{x,y}{\Psi}$ is closed for any $(x,y)\in S^1$, then the union in the above equation is closed, so $F^{-1}(S^1 \setminus U)$ is the product of closed sets and hence closed. Therefore $F^{-1}(U)$ is open, so $F$ is continuous and it follows that $f\simeq g$. $\Box$

**Edit 1:** Per some comments here is a more explicit version, viewing $S^1\subset \mathbb C$.

For each $x\in S^1$ define the function $h_x:[a,b]\to S^1$ via $h_x (t)=e^{2\pi i t}$, where $a:= \min (\{t\in I \mid e^{2\pi i t} =x \})$, and $b= a+1/2$, if $\operatorname{Im}(x)\geq 0$, or $a-1/2$ otherwise.

Then define $F$ via $F(x,t)=h_x (a+(b-a)t)$ and up to homeomorphism $F$ is a homotopy from $f$ to $g$.

Comment: It is not clear to me why $F^{-1}(S^1 \setminus U)$ is what you claim. And you should define $F$ more explicitely and synthetically. E.g. (viewing $S^1$ as a subset of $\Bbb C$) $F(z,t)=e^{i\pi t}z$ (obviously continuous).

Comment: @Jacaré your $F(t,x,y)$ is constantly $(-x,-y)$! except for $t=1/2,$ where it is undefined...

Comment: F(t,x,y)=gt+(1-t)f works? I mean it works But not extraordinarily sure though.

Comment: @SafalDasBiswas No, I don't think so. In your suggestion $F(1/2,1,0)=(0,0)\notin S^1$.

Comment: Yeah you are right

Comment: Let's think then bit wait

Comment: $F_{K,R}(t,x,y)=t^{K}f(x,y)+g(x,y)(1-t)^{R}$                                                     $$K\neq R$$ are reals positive, Such K and R may exist.

Comment: Is it? Work I am not sure again just trying

Comment: Your "edit1" is extraordinarily complicated *and unproved*. Why didn't you simply adopt my $F(z,t)=e^{i\pi t}z,$ which completely solves your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented some hours before the two previous answers, viewing $S^1$ as a subset of $\Bbb C,$ the (obviously continuous) map
$$F:S^1 \times I\to S^1,\quad(z,t)\mapsto e^{i\pi t}z$$
is a homotopy from $f={\rm id}_{S^1}$ to $g=-{\rm id}_{S^1}.$

If you insist on staying in $\Bbb R^2,$ rewrite it
$$F\left((x,y),t\right)=(x\cos(\pi t)-y\sin(\pi t),x\sin(\pi t)+y\cos(\pi t)).$$

Comment: Sorry I did not read your comment before writing my answer.  Anyway, we are all saying the same thing.  Always better to write an answer directly than a comment! :-)

Comment: I will accept your answer since it was originally suggested in the comments before the other answers. I did not verbatim use your comment in my answer since this is a HW assignment and my solution is supposed to be original. But at any rate, yes, this is the most elegant solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The map that sends each point $(x,y)$ to its antipodal point $(-x,-y)$ in the circle is the same as rotation by 180 degrees.  The identity map is rotation by o degrees.  The homotopy consists of all the rotations by intermediate amounts, from $0$ to $\pi$ radians.

I'll leave it up to you to formalize, but it's a lot easier than your long winded proof.

Comment: Thanks. So if $\theta$ is the angle from the positive $x$-axis to $(x,y)$, I believe the function $F(x,y,t)=(\cos(\theta + \pi t),\sin(\theta + \pi t))$ should work. How do you prove continuity?

Comment: That's the right idea, although better expressed using complex numbers.  Rotation by an angle $\theta$ is multiplication by $e^{i\theta}$.  So the whole homotopy can be described as the map $S^1\times[0,1]\to S^1$ sending $(z,t)$ to $ze^{i\pi t}$.  Here $t$ varies between $0$ and $1$, so the angle varies between $0$ and $\pi$.  This is obviously continuous as the product of continuous maps.

Comment: See my self-answer. I believe the maps are equivalent.

Comment: Yes, it's the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @PatrickR for suggesting to use trigonometric functions and a simple rotation.

*Proof.* We proceed to show $f$ and $g$ are homotopic by construction of a homotopy ${F:S^1 \times I\to S^1}$ from $f$ to $g$.
For each $(x,y)\in S^1$, we note that $(x,y)=(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ for some angle $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$ with respect to the positive $x$-axis. In view of this fact, define $F$ via ${F(x,y,t)=(\cos(\theta+\pi t),\sin(\theta + \pi t))}$, and we claim $F$ is a homotopy from $f$ to $g$. When $t=0$, we obtain the identity map $f$. When $t=1$, the map $F$ represents a rotation counterclockwise by $\pi$ radians or $180^\circ$, which is equivalent to the rotation $(x,y)\mapsto (-x,-y)$ defined by $g$. Finally, since $F$ is composed of elementary trignometric functions, it is continuous. Hence $F$ is a homotopy and $f\simeq g$ as desired. $\Box$

Comment: A minor thing: the map $(x,y)\mapsto (-x,-y)$ is not a translation.  It's still a rotation.  It's kind of an inversion in the center of the circle.

Comment: Yeah. I guess in my head when I wrote "translation" I had $S^1$ embedded in $\mathbb R^2$ in my mind and imagined a translation instead of the rotation.

Comment: Your proof is basically ok.  There are infinitely many $\theta$ that corresponds to a point on the circle, unless you retrict the angle to the half-open interval $[0,2\pi)$.  But then you should still show continuity at $\theta=0$ as going "the other way" you get angles close to $2\pi$.  All unnecessary hassle if you do the following for example: expand the cosine and sine of the sums in the formula for $F$ and replace $\cos\theta$ by $x$ and similarly for $y$.  The result is a simple continuous formula involving only $x$, $y$ and $t$.  (Or use complex numbers :-)

Comment: I did indeed specify $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$. I'm not sure about the rest of your statement.